# Laravel 6.2 Authentification Error : LoginController does not exist

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-authentication, laravel-6.2

I'm beginner in laravel framework so I don't understand lot of thing in laravel for the moment.

So, I have try to create an simple authentication system.

But when I try to use the form I have this error :

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [Application\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController] does not exist.
```

(you can get the complete error here : https://flareapp.io/share/Bm0AY6Px#F29)

However, the LoginController class exist in my folder so I don't understood what append.

I have write this commands : `php artisan ui vue --auth`
And i have configured my database, the only change that I have made is on the migrate of user table.
My user up function look like that :

```php
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('nom');
            $table->string('prenom');
            $table->string('telephone',10);
            $table->string('adresse');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

To solve that, I have try to :

- reinstall the projet with auth flag like that: `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel myprojet --auth`.
- Init nodejs like that : `npm install` and `npm run dev`
- Don't change the user migrate  file.

So if you can help me and explain how this auth system work that will be realy helpful for me.

Comment: What is "this error"? Is there any error message involved? Please add it to your question

Comment: the link that I have send is my error return. Directly export and share with flareapp.io

Comment: Please add all error messages to your question by editing it. Also explain what you've tried to solve them

Comment: Ok it's updated ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. composer require laravel/ui
2. `php artisan ui vue` or `php artisan ui react`

https://readouble.com/laravel/6.x/en/frontend.html